# Redirect user on form submit after API response in the background

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, paypal

I am not sure how it can be done.

What I am trying to do is.

I have a Paypal subscription form.

when a user clicks on Subscribe,
An Ajax call is made to Paypal API and an authorization token is obtained.

Now I want to redirect the user/customer to Paypal after the token is received to complete the subscription with the authorization token.

Now my question is I can make the ajax call and get the response,

But after that how I can redirect the customer to paypal alongwith urlencoded-data is the question.

**Update**

The second request will be like this which should redirect to Paypal at the same time.

`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=InsertTokenHere`

Comment: `window.location = newURL` will redirect to the new URL.

Comment: I want to encode the values in the URL after the response is received from Paypal. will I be able to do that. Updating the question and request which is needed to be sent.

Comment: Take a look at `$.param()` in jQuery, it can be used to URL-encode an object or array.